# Web service without apache, jetty, ... or another server

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I need to create SOAP web service without using some web server(apache, jetty, ...).

javax.jws.WebService seems best option, but I know how it work in production mode.

Someone using javax.jws.WebService? It will be work with 100 online users?

Maybe some advise about other web service options?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't serve a web service without having some sort of server. It's like asking "I want to drive a car, but the car must not have an engine".

Comment: If you consider running a web service hard, how about writing one?

Answer (score 3):

It can easily support 100 users, rather you will need to make it support 100 users ;)
You can implement the webservice without webservers but then you will end up coding all the features that the webserver's provide to you like:
  -- Multiple request processing or scalability
  -- Authentication, authorization, auditing.

I you could tell me why do you want to hand code the webservice platform it would be helpful.

Comment: I dont have experience work with webservers. How you understend its will be hard for me to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Some WebServers can run in embedded mode (jetty for example).